# Solve the equation $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{9-x}=\sqrt{2x-12}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{9-x}=\sqrt{2x-12}$$

I know the equation is pretty simple, but I'm interested in other solutions!

You can't square it! I want to find a good solution without squaring and without derivative

**My attempt:**

$$\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x+1}=a, & a\geq 0\\ 
\sqrt{9-x}=b, & b\geq 0
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
x+1=a^2\\
9-x=b^2
\end{cases}\Rightarrow a^2-b^2-4=2x-12$$
$$a-b=\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}\Leftrightarrow \frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{(a+b)}=\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}\Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}}{a^2-b^2}\Leftrightarrow a+b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}}$$
$$\begin{cases}
a-b=\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}\\
a+b=\cfrac{a^2-b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}}
\end{cases}\Rightarrow 2a=\frac{a^2-b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}}+\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}\Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2a=\frac{a^2-b^2+a^2-b^2-4}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-4}}\Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt{x+1}=\frac{4x-20}{\sqrt{2x-12}}\Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{2x-12}=4x-20\Leftrightarrow$$ $$\Leftrightarrow 4(x+1)(2x-12)=16x^2-160x+400\Rightarrow x=\left \{ 7,8 \right \}$$

*Are there other ways that would be easier?*

Comment: Sorry I lost the part "You can't square it!"

Comment: But the very first thing you do is square it in your solution! Where you say $\sqrt{x+1}=a$ and then $a^2=x+1$, isn't that squaring?

Comment: Yes, squaring it, but not immediately. Agree, when we square at once, there are complex calculations, but when I squared at the end, I got a quadratic equation. And I squared it once, and in your solution you need to square it twice

Comment: It's not too hard or messy to write this same technique in just the variable $x$ without introducing $a$ and $b$. The same technique could be applied to $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{2x-12}$ or $\sqrt{9-x}+\sqrt{2x-12}$, working out essentially the same.

Comment: The arithmetic at the end is a little simpler if you divide both sides of the equation by $2$ just before squaring.

Comment: "Are there other ways that would be easier?" Yes, squaring the starting equation.

Comment: In your attempt, you square in second to last line anyway, so I don't see the point really in avoiding doing it right at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{9-x}=\sqrt{2x-12}$$

for real solutions requires $(x+1)\ge 0$ , $(9-x)\ge 0$, $2x-12 \ge 0$ that is $6\le x \le 9$, which leads, by inspection, to the integer solutions $x=7$ and $x=8$.

Now we need to prove that there are not other solutions.

At this aim, let $x+1=y^2$ then we obtain the equivalent

$$y=\sqrt{10-y^2}+\sqrt{2y^2-14}$$

and since RHS is the sum of two concave functions it is also concave and we can't have more than two solutions.

Comment: We proved that there can't be more than two solutions, but why do you think the solutions will be integers? A solution can be irrational

Comment: @Partim In the first part by inspection on the domain $[6,9]$ we find that $x=7$ and $x=8$ are solutions. In the second part we show that there are not more than two and this conlcludes the proof. I'm not claiming that this is a general method which always works.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:**
$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{9-x}=\sqrt{2x-12}
\\ 10-2\sqrt{(x+1)(9-x)}=2x-12
\\ 11-x=\sqrt{(x+1)(9-x)}
\\ x^2 +121 -22x = -x^2 +8x +9
\\ x^2 +56 - 15x=0
\\ (x-7)(x-8) =0
$$

Comment: I asked you, you can't square and use the derivative